# Which One is better With Join Keyword or Without Join Keyword for this query

Tags: mysql

I have md_members table with more than 15,00,000 rows... To get performance which is better -join query with join keyword/without join keyword ....

```
Select 
     mem_fname
    ,mem_lname
    ,mem_mobile
    ,mem_email
    ,wda_first_login
    ,a.updated_on as wda_last_login 
From wda_article_log as a,md_members as b 
where b.mem_id=a.mem_id and a.article_type=1 and b.wda_status=1`
```

Comment: Have you looked at the return values of the MySQL explain command?

Comment: Not sure how my sql behaves but some one told me that MS Sql for such queries creates execution plan using inner join. But explicitly providing inner join you ensure that it is using join plus make it more readable.

Comment: I guess you will get the highest performance with a good indexes (at least on mem_id in both tables - if not primary key - and maybe even article_type and/or wda_status)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explicit `inner join` and the comma syntax are equivalent in terms of performance. You can check the output of `explain` for both versions, they will yield the same query plan.

There is a difference in the precedence of these operators, so if you mix them, you may have some nasty surprises, but in the query in the question this is not the case.

The reason for using an explicit `inner join` over an implicit one is that the code is better readable because the join conditions and the filtering criteria are separated from each other.